# How do I select every pair of consecutive events in Hive?

Tags: hive

Imagine I have Hive table T with consecutive events:

```
n
---
1
2
3
4
...
```

I need to write some code to select every pair of consecutive events from this table. Currently I have a solution like

```
select t1.n, min(t2.n) from t t1 join t t2 where t1.n < t2.n group by t1.n;
```

Which is very ineffective even for relatively small table (thousands of rows) as it produces temporary cartesian product of table on itself (i.e. O(n^2) in complexity).

I would like to find less expensive (hopefully linear) solution to the same problem.

Comment: This sounds like something that could be solved much more easily using a procedural approach, e.g. using python, assuming you can export an ordered view of your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to 0.11 you can use a UDF (for example [Nexr's](https://github.com/nexr/hive-udf))
Currently there is only a `lag` function but that should do it in your case if you'll query :
`select n as "next" , lag(n) "previous" from t;`

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer myself.

As of Hive 0.11 windowing and analytics functions were introduced: https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-windowingandanalytics.html

So the query I was looking for is:

```
select n, lead(n) from t;
```